# How to get error(difference between point and fitted curve) and plot error with curve?

Tags: fitting

It's embarassing to ask this type of question but I searched a lot and there is no way I can find to get the difference between plot and curve.

I plotted prime numbers and got fitted curve. But I cannot get difference between the plot and fitted curve. R squared and least square are not appropriate I think. Please can anyone give me a hint?

[image]
[image]

Some code:

```
ws = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37}
p1 = ListPlot[ws]
fit = Fit[ws, {1, x, x^2}, x];
p2 = Plot[fit, {x, 0, 12}];
Show[p1, p2]
```

Comment: Please post your code as text rather than in a picture.  You'll get more folks willing to help.

Comment: Please don't replace your question with "Thank you!"

Comment: Could a kind soul please add the code in text format, as Woochul seems to be unable or unwilling to do so?

Answer (score 8):

When one needs such things as the residuals (which I would argue is all of the time), use `LinearModelFit`:

```
ws = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37}
ListPlot[ws]
lm = LinearModelFit[ws, {x, x^2}, x]
lm["FitResiduals"]

(* {0.398352, -0.297952, -0.293457, -0.588162, 0.817932, -0.0751748, 
    0.732517, -0.758991, -0.5497, 1.36039, -1.02872, 0.282967} *)
```

Comment: I really appreciate it Mr. code master

Answer (score 1):

Another way is simply to compute the difference between the fit function you defined and the original values at the given points e.g.

```
ws = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37};
p1 = ListPlot[ws];
wsfit[x_] = Fit[ws, {1, x, x^2}, x];
p2 = Plot[wsfit[x], {x, 0, 12}];
ListPlot[wsfit[Range[12]]-ws]
```

which yields the same values

```
(*{-0.398352, 0.297952, 0.293457, 0.588162, -0.817932, 0.0751748, -0.732517,
0.758991, 0.5497, -1.36039, 1.02872, -0.282967}*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate it!!